# SQL Server 2008: sentencia join arrojando resultados incorrectos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando unir estas dos tablas

Tabla **Producto**:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+--------+--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+------------------+---------+---------------+--------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Id_Sucursal | Id_Producto |              Clave_Eq_Sisco               |      Num_Serie       | No_Parte |  OEM  | Cod_Barras | Marca |         Modelo         | Original | Linea | Nuevo |                Descr_Larga                |     Descr_Corta      | Existencia | Costo | Impuesto | Utilidad | Precio | Oferta | Precio_Oferta | Cantidad |  F_Inicio  |   F_Fin    | Precio_Maximo | Precio_Minimo | Maximo | Minimo | Compatibilidades | Estatus | Observaciones | Codigo |   F_Alta   | Usr_Alta |   F_Baja   | Usr_Baja | rendimiento | estatus_oc | porcentaje_maximo | porcentaje_minimo |
+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+--------+--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+------------------+---------+---------------+--------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| CORDOBA     |        1219 | TORCSAMSAN0000001219                      | 28837                |          | 28837 | 28837      | SAMS  |                        | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER BOTELLA ALTERNO 220G                |                      |         43 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 12/03/2013 | 12/03/2013 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 12/03/2013 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |        5000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| TEHUACAN    |        1219 | TORCSAMSAN0000001219                      | 28837                |          | 28837 | 28837      | SAMS  |                        | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER BOTELLA ALTERNO 220G                |                      |         31 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 12/03/2013 | 12/03/2013 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 12/03/2013 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |        5000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| XALAPA      |        1219 | TORCSAMSAN0000001219                      | 28837                |          | 28837 | 28837      | SAMS  |                        | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER BOTELLA ALTERNO 220G                |                      |         10 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 12/03/2013 | 12/03/2013 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 12/03/2013 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |        5000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| CORDOBA     |         612 | TORCHEPAAN0000000612                      | 32385                |          | 32385 | 32385      | HEPA  | LASER JET-1012         | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER RECARGA GENERICO  100 G HP          |                      |          1 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 18/12/2012 | 18/12/2012 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 18/12/2012 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |           0 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| TEHUACAN    |         612 | TORCHEPAAN0000000612                      | 32385                |          | 32385 | 32385      | HEPA  | LASER JET-1012         | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER RECARGA GENERICO  100 G HP          |                      |          8 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 18/12/2012 | 18/12/2012 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 18/12/2012 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |           0 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| XALAPA      |         612 | TORCHEPAAN0000000612                      | 32385                |          | 32385 | 32385      | HEPA  | LASER JET-1012         | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER RECARGA GENERICO  100 G HP          |                      |         11 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 18/12/2012 | 18/12/2012 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 18/12/2012 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |           0 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| CORDOBA     |         717 | TORCKATUAN0000000717                      | 37069                | 37069    | 37069 | 37069      | SHAR  | AL-2031                | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO  240 G  SHARP     |                      |          8 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 20/12/2012 | 20/12/2012 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 20/12/2012 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |        5000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| TEHUACAN    |         717 | TORCKATUAN0000000717                      | 37069                | 37069    | 37069 | 37069      | SHAR  | AL-2031                | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO  240 G  SHARP     |                      |         15 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 20/12/2012 | 20/12/2012 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 20/12/2012 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |        5000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| XALAPA      |         717 | TORCKATUAN0000000717                      | 37069                | 37069    | 37069 | 37069      | SHAR  | AL-2031                | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO  240 G  SHARP     |                      |         11 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 20/12/2012 | 20/12/2012 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 20/12/2012 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |        5000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| CORDOBA     |        1023 | TORCKATUAN0000001023                      | TK-1147-172--137-162 | 44259    | 44259 | 29458      | KYMI  |                        | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO 290GR. KYOCERA    |                      |         19 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 17/01/2013 | 17/01/2013 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 17/01/2013 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |        7000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| TEHUACAN    |        1023 | TORCKATUAN0000001023                      | TK-1147-172--137-162 | 44259    | 44259 | 29458      | KYMI  |                        | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO 290GR. KYOCERA    |                      |         27 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 17/01/2013 | 17/01/2013 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 17/01/2013 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |        7000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| XALAPA      |        1023 | TORCKATUAN0000001023                      | TK-1147-172--137-162 | 44259    | 44259 | 29458      | KYMI  |                        | A        | TORC  | N     | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO 290GR. KYOCERA    |                      |         18 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 17/01/2013 | 17/01/2013 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 17/01/2013 | SUP      | 01/01/1900 |          |        7000 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| CORDOBA     |        1803 | TINCHEPADESKJETADVANTAGE-2515ON0000001803 | # 662                | CZ103AL  |       | CZ103AL    | HEPA  | DESKJET ADVANTAGE-2515 | O        | TINC  | N     | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP NEGRO # 662    | CARTUCHO NEGRO #662  |          0 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 08/02/2014 | 08/02/2014 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 08/02/2014 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |         100 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| TEHUACAN    |        1803 | TINCHEPADESKJETADVANTAGE-2515ON0000001803 | # 662                | CZ103AL  |       | CZ103AL    | HEPA  | DESKJET ADVANTAGE-2515 | O        | TINC  | N     | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP NEGRO # 662    | CARTUCHO NEGRO #662  |          0 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 08/02/2014 | 08/02/2014 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 08/02/2014 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |         100 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| XALAPA      |        1803 | TINCHEPADESKJETADVANTAGE-2515ON0000001803 | # 662                | CZ103AL  |       | CZ103AL    | HEPA  | DESKJET ADVANTAGE-2515 | O        | TINC  | N     | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP NEGRO # 662    | CARTUCHO NEGRO #662  |          1 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 08/02/2014 | 08/02/2014 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 08/02/2014 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |         100 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| CORDOBA     |        1802 | TINCHEPADESKJETADVANTAGE-2515ON0000001802 | 662                  | CZ104AL  |       | CZ104AL    | HEPA  | DESKJET ADVANTAGE-2515 | O        | TINC  | N     | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP TRICOLOR # 662 | CARTUCHO # 662 TRICO |          0 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 08/02/2014 | 08/02/2014 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 08/02/2014 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |         100 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| TEHUACAN    |        1802 | TINCHEPADESKJETADVANTAGE-2515ON0000001802 | 662                  | CZ104AL  |       | CZ104AL    | HEPA  | DESKJET ADVANTAGE-2515 | O        | TINC  | N     | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP TRICOLOR # 662 | CARTUCHO # 662 TRICO |          0 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 08/02/2014 | 08/02/2014 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 08/02/2014 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |         100 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
| XALAPA      |        1802 | TINCHEPADESKJETADVANTAGE-2515ON0000001802 | 662                  | CZ104AL  |       | CZ104AL    | HEPA  | DESKJET ADVANTAGE-2515 | O        | TINC  | N     | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP TRICOLOR # 662 | CARTUCHO # 662 TRICO |          1 |     0 |       16 |        0 |      0 | N      |             0 |        0 | 08/02/2014 | 08/02/2014 |             0 |             0 |      0 |      0 |                  | A       |               |        | 08/02/2014 | COMPRAS  | 01/01/1900 |          |         100 |            |                 0 |                 0 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+--------+--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+------------------+---------+---------------+--------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Tabla **Kardex_Producto**:

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------+----------+-------+----------+-------+--------+--------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
    | Id_Sucursal | Id_Movimiento | Tipo_Movimiento |      Num_Serie       | No_Parte |  OEM  | Cantidad | Costo | Codigo | Oferta |    Ord_Compra    | No_Factura | Ord_Salida | No_Transferencia | No_Contrato |   No_Servicio    | Aut_Especial | Observaciones | Estatus | F_Entrada  | Usr_Entrada |  F_Salida  | Usr_Salida |
    +-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------+----------+-------+----------+-------+--------+--------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
    | XALAPA      |           504 | E+              | 28837                |          | 28837 |       10 |     0 |        | N      | Traspaso No. 543 |            |            |                  |             | Traspaso No. 543 |              |               | F       | 10/10/2016 | TCAXALGER   | 01/01/1900 |            |
    | XALAPA      |           504 | E+              | 32385                |          | 32385 |        5 |     0 |        | N      | Traspaso No. 543 |            |            |                  |             | Traspaso No. 543 |              |               | F       | 10/10/2016 | TCAXALGER   | 01/01/1900 |            |
    | XALAPA      |           504 | E+              | 37069                | 37069    | 37069 |       10 |     0 |        | N      | Traspaso No. 543 |            |            |                  |             | Traspaso No. 543 |              |               | F       | 10/10/2016 | TCAXALGER   | 01/01/1900 |            |
    | XALAPA      |           504 | E+              | TK-1147-172--137-162 | 44259    | 44259 |       10 |     0 |        | N      | Traspaso No. 543 |            |            |                  |             | Traspaso No. 543 |              |               | F       | 10/10/2016 | TCAXALGER   | 01/01/1900 |            |
    | XALAPA      |           505 | E+              | # 662                | CZ103AL  |       |        1 |     0 |        | N      | Traspaso No. 549 |            |            |                  |             | Traspaso No. 549 |              |               | F       | 13/10/2016 | TCAXALGER   | 01/01/1900 |            |
    | XALAPA      |           505 | E+              | 662                  | CZ104AL  |       |        1 |     0 |        | N      | Traspaso No. 549 |            |            |                  |             | Traspaso No. 549 |              |               | F       | 13/10/2016 | TCAXALGER   | 01/01/1900 |            |
    +-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------+----------+-------+----------+-------+--------+--------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Para hacer un reporte que muestre, de la tabla Kardex_Producto, Id_Sucursal, Id_Movimiento, Cantidad, Costo, Ord_Compra y, en lugar del num_serie, o No_parte, u OEM, muestre Descr_Larga de la tabla Producto.

Intenté esta sentencia:

```
SELECT Producto.Descr_Larga, Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal, 
       Kardex_Producto.Id_Movimiento, Kardex_Producto.Cantidad, 
       Kardex_Producto.Costo, Kardex_Producto.Ord_Compra FROM   Kardex_Producto  JOIN   Producto 
         ON Kardex_Producto.No_Parte = Producto.No_Parte 
        and Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal = 'xalapa'
        and Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal = Producto.Id_Sucursal WHERE (   Kardex_Producto.F_Entrada >= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161001', 103) 
       OR Kardex_Producto.F_Salida  >= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161001', 103)
      )
```

pero devuelve resultados erróneos (filas repetidas) cuando debería retornar algo parecido a

```
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+--------+------------------+------------+------------+
|      Num_Serie       |                Descr_Larga                | Id_Sucursal | Id_Movimiento | Cantidad | Costo  |    Ord_Compra    | F_Entrada  |  F_Salida  |
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+--------+------------------+------------+------------+
| 28837                | TONER BOTELLA ALTERNO 220G                | Xalapa      |           504 |       10 | 398    | Traspaso No. 543 | 10/10/2016 | 01/01/1900 |
| 32385                | TONER RECARGA GENERICO  100 G HP          | Xalapa      |           504 |        5 | 130    | Traspaso No. 543 | 10/10/2016 | 01/01/1900 |
| 37069                | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO  240 G  SHARP     | Xalapa      |           504 |       10 | 230    | Traspaso No. 543 | 10/10/2016 | 01/01/1900 |
| TK-1147-172--137-162 | TONER  RECARGA GENERICO 290GR. KYOCERA    | Xalapa      |           504 |       10 | 398    | Traspaso No. 543 | 10/10/2016 | 01/01/1900 |
| # 662                | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP NEGRO # 662    | Xalapa      |           505 |        1 | 185.76 | Traspaso No. 549 | 13/10/2016 | 01/01/1900 |
| 662                  | CARTUCHO TINTA ORIGINAL HP TRICOLOR # 662 | Xalapa      |           505 |        1 | 185.76 | Traspaso No. 549 | 13/10/2016 | 01/01/1900 |
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+--------+------------------+------------+------------+
```

en realidad devuelve información repetida

```
+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+-------+------------------+
|                     Descr_Larga                      | Id_Sucursal | Id_Movimiento | Cantidad | Costo |    Ord_Compra    |
+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+-------+------------------+
| TONER CARTUCHO REMANOFACTURADO                       | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| TONER CARTUCHO  GENERICO EQUIVALENTE A TN-850  HP    | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| BALERO DE RODILLO DE PRESION                         | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
|                                                      | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
|                                                      | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
|                                                      | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
|                                                      | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
|                                                      | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| CHIP CARTUCHO XEROX 013R00601                        | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| LAMINA ALTERNO CANON IR-1600                         | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| TONER HP RECARGA  COLOR NEGRO 55 GRS CHIP INCLUIDO   | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| TONER RECARGA HP COLOR CYAN 45GRS CHIP INCLUIDO      | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| TONER RECARGA HP COLOR MAGENTA 45 GRS CHIP INCLUIDO  | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| RECARGA TONER HP COLOR AMARILLO 45 GRS CHIP INCLUIDO | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| CHIP CARTUCHO CE321A CYAN                            | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| CHIP CARTUCHO MAGENTA CE323A                         | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| CHIP CARTUCHO CE320A                                 | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| CHIP CARTUCHO HP COLOR AMARILLO CE322A               | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| TONER RECARGA GENERICO  195G. LEXMARK                | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
| CHIP  GENERICO  LEXMARK                              | XALAPA      |           504 |       10 |   398 | Traspaso No. 543 |
+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+-------+------------------+
```

Y no entiendo por qué, o cómo solucionarlo...

Agradezco de antemano todo su apoyo.

Comment: para poder entender esto, necesitamos saber cuáles son las claves primarias de ambas tablas

Comment: puedes aplicar `INNER JOIN?`

Comment: @sioesi: Es lo que está haciendo ya.

Comment: retiro lo dicho @sstan

Comment: @stan no veo el inner por ninguna parte, yo siempre lo pongo

Comment: @ras212 funcionalmente hacen lo mismo

Comment: @sioesi no sólo funcionalmente, un `JOIN` sin tener escrito explícitamente `INNER` o `OUTER` **es** un `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Lamak gracias por la aclaracion

Comment: @antonio_veneroso puedos mostrarnos el codigo de generacion de las 2 tablas y un script para insertar algunos valores? De otra forma no puedo reproducir la salida que nos muestras ni encontrar el error.

Comment: De la tabla Producto, la clave primaria es Id_Sucursal, Id_Producto. La clave primaria de Kardex_Producto es Id_Sucursal, Id_Movimiento, Tipo_Movimiento, Num_Serie

Comment: @antonio_veneroso en ese caso, el "problema" está más que claro. Obtienes más resultados porque la tabla `Kardex_Producto` tiene varias filas para un producto/sucursal. Además, `No_Parte` ni siquiera es parte de la llave de ninguna de ambas tablas?

Comment: @Lamak, tiene algo que ver que No_Parte no forme parte de la clave en ninguna de las tablas? Podrías indicarme, si hay, alguna forma de modificar las tablas para que la información pueda ser recuperada correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no funciona mal. Ten en cuenta que estás cruzando valores nulos (o en blanco) del campo No_Parte junto con los valores de Id_Sucursal. Si hay valores repetidos te saldrán tantos valores repetidos como coincidencias haya. Es decir: Si tienes dos valores iguales en un campo y otros 3 en otro, te saldrán 6.

Si quieres hacer este tipo de cruces y que te devuelva un solo registro vas a tener que buscar valores únicos.

Comment: Si revisaras bien las tablas que puse, notarías que sí está mal, pues no coincide la información arrojada por el join a la información contenida en Kardex_Producto. Gracias por tu aporte :-)

Comment: Mmmmm, no estoy muy seguro pero yo quitaría una de estas dos:

Comment: Mmmmmm, no estoy muy seguro pero yo quitaría una de estas dos:

and Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal = 'xalapa'
and Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal = Producto.Id_Sucursal

Creo que por ahí pueden venirte los problemas.

Comment: si quito `Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal='Xalapa'` arrojaría los resultados de todas las sucursales; si quito `Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal=Producto.Id_Sucursal` salen aún más filas duplicadas.

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos formas de solucionar esto:

1. Agregar `distinct`: ejemplo `Select distinct` ...
2. Agrupando tu resultado

Estas soluciones se me ocurren, espero que te puedan ayudar en algo.  Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que estas metiendo una condicion errónea en el join.
Prueba con esto:

```
    SELECT Producto.Descr_Larga, Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal, 
         Kardex_Producto.Id_Movimiento, Kardex_Producto.Cantidad, 
         Kardex_Producto.Costo, Kardex_Producto.Ord_Compra FROM Kardex_Producto  JOIN   Producto 
     ON Kardex_Producto.No_Parte = Producto.No_Parte 
    and Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal = Producto.Id_Sucursal WHERE ((   Kardex_Producto.F_Entrada >= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161001', 103) 
   OR Kardex_Producto.F_Salida  >= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161001', 103)
  ) and Kardex_Producto.Id_Sucursal = 'xalapa')
```

Deberia funcionar. El error es que estas metiendo una condicion general dentro del join que se utiliza para "emparejar" dos o mas tablas.
Espero te sirva

Comment: Esto no debería tener ninguna diferencia con el código que se muestra en la pregunta